# How to set ipv6 next hop?

Tags: routing, ipv6

I have a tunnelling tool that will encap an ipv4 packet in ipv6 packet. However I am not able to configure route to ipv6 next-hop
!https://s21.postimg.org/gxddc2s2v/Screen_Shot_2016_11_01_at_11_52_01_PM.png (Topology)

My next-hop is 2003::1:70:16:234, which is reachable

```
machine1:/tmp# ping6 2003::1:70:16:234
PING 2003::1:70:16:234(2003::1:70:16:234) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2003::1:70:16:234: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.29 ms
64 bytes from 2003::1:70:16:234: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.73 ms
64 bytes from 2003::1:70:16:234: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.75 ms

--- 2003::1:70:16:234 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.731/2.590/4.290/1.203 ms
```

As I try to add route so as to route ipv4 packet destined to 8.8.8.0/24 through next hop/gw as 2003::1:70:16:234/64, it fails

```
machine1:/tmp#  route add -net 8.8.8.0/24 gw 2003::1:70:16:234/64
2003::1:70:16:234/64: **Unknown host  <<<<<<<<<---- ERROR**
```

However when tried to set next hop as an IPv4 address, route add is successful.

```
machine1:/tmp#  route add -net 8.8.8.0/24 gw 1.70.16.234
machine1:/tmp#  route del -net 8.8.8.0/24 gw 1.70.16.234
```

Any input on what's so fundamentally wrong in my `route` command?

Answer (score 3):

What's fundamentally wrong here is that IPv4 and IPv6 are completely different protocols. You can't route IPv4 traffic to IPv6 addresses.

I suspect you are trying to *tunnel* IPv4 traffic somewhere, but since you've given no details about that, it's impossible to say anything further.

Comment: Yes, i have a tool running on same machine that tunnels ipv4 (inner) packet into ipv6 (outer) packet.

Comment: Added topology diagram for more info on my network setup.

Comment: giving point to point IPs on tunnel interfaces(remote and local) and give the static route on those point to point IPs!

Comment: Strictly speaking this is a limitation of the implementation rather than of the protocols. For both IPv4 and IPv6 the next hop address is used to find the hardware address of the next hop and the packet is then delivered to that hardware address. By the time the packet is delivered there is no longer any indication of how the sender found the hardware address to send it to. Thus it would be entirely possible to implement a stack which can use ND to find a hardware address to send an IPv4 packet too. But just because it is possible it doesn't mean that it should be done.